# How to fix a generated Error: Enoent? A result from a command line to install Zurb Foundation for Apps

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower, zurb-foundation-apps

I installed Node.js and updated my $PATH environment. However after several attempts to install zurb foundation for apps I get the same errors. How do I go about fixing it? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I run this command...

```
npm install -g foundation-cli bower gulp
```

I get the following errors

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/upload.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:849:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/index.js:54:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CachingRegistryClient.RegClient (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/index.js:50:42)
    at new CachingRegistryClient (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:20:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:363:22
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:82:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:13
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "foundation-cli" "bower" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/upload.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall stat

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/upload.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `upload.js` is a file that should be in that directory. I had this exact same error. I went to that directory and typed `ls -a`

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jay   admin   105 Dec  7  2013 upload.js -> ../../../../../../Cellar/node/0.10.22/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/upload.js
```

It was an old symlink to a version of node long gone installed with `homebrew`. I remove the symlink reinstalled node, no upload.js was installed so I don't think it's even a file that exist in the current node.
But it works now for me!!

Comment: Thanks! It's all good now. You were right it was that stupid symlink - I totally forgotten that I used homebrew back in the day for a hackathon project. I haven't use it since. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Yes, looking into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` is certainly the right thing to do. For me the reasons leading to that were, that I had a symbolic link there, pointing into a gone location (my mistake). Deleting that link as the most simple solution...